# Unable to access attribute after fetch

Tags: javascript, attributes, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am testing some code in my web console (using coffescript)

```
@user = new Onethingaday.Models.User()
@user.url= "/users/#{current_user.get('nickname')}.json?id_type=nickname"
@user.fetch()
console.log(@user)
console.log(@user.get("facebook_id"))
```

The `console.log(@user)` line shows the following:
[image]

However, `console.log(@user.get("facebook_id"))` shows `undefined`.

I see that `user` has the `facebook_id` attribute. How do I retrieve the value of it?

Comment: `User` is a Backbone.js model, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a timing issue, albeit an odd one. `fetch` is asynchronous; you need to wait until its `success` callback is called before trying to access any attributes.

Try this:

```
@user.fetch success: =>
  console.log(@user)
  console.log(@user.get("facebook_id"))
```

It's confusing that the first `console.log` would show `user.attributes.facebook_id` existing and the second wouldn't, but `console.log` is itself asynchronous in Webkit's implementation, so what's going on is that the `@user.get` call is being resolved immediately (synchronously), whereas the object inspection in the first `console.log` is resolving later—after the `fetch` completed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like facebook_id is a property of the attributes property of the @user object. If that's the case, I'd think the following would work:

```
@user.attributes.facebook_id
```