# Coffeescript / Javascript - why object attribute is undefined?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this function that I'm using it in a Rails 3.1 project:

```
setPosition: (object) ->
    console.log object
    console.log object.width
    object["position"] = [500, 50] 
    this
```

The `console.log object` gives

```
Object
    height: 600
    position: Array[2]
    title: "Banner for Creative"
    width: 160
    __proto__: Object
```

but `console.log object.width` is undefined. Why ?

Comment: Please don't name your variables `object`, use a more descriptive name that avoids ambiguity with native objects.

Comment: Is this in chrome by any chance?

Comment: jm: your are right. I already changed it.

Comment: same behavior in Firefox

Comment: Could you add results for `console.log (x for x of object)` and `console.log 'width' of object`? It may be that there's a subtle string issue, such as the key name having a null character at the end. See my answer on another question today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8344503/66226

Comment: @TrevorBurnham console.log (x for x of object) gives ["title"] and console.log 'width od object gives false

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question just a couple of days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8299394/66226

Basically, `console.log` has some asynchronous behaviors (in some environments). So when you pass in a reference to an object, that object is stringified later—whereas `object.width` is `undefined` right now.

If you do

```
console.log object.toString()
```

then you should get more consistent results (though less pretty ones).

**Edit:** Or better yet,

```
console.log JSON.stringify(object)
```

See comments below.

Comment: +1 - I *assumed* he was getting an error.  I never imagined console.log would have issues like this

Comment: Adam, I'm not getting an error, just 'undefined'. But if I try to access width or height directly ( object.height for instance ) same behavior.

Comment: console.log object.toString() gives [object Object]

Comment: @Aldo Ah, sorry; try `JSON.stringify(object)` instead of `object.toString()`.

Comment: JSON.stringify only shows title attribute. console.log object shows the rest. Object
    height: 600
    title: "Banner for Creative"
    width: 160
    __proto__: Object
{"title":"Banner for Creative"}

Comment: Thanks Trevor for your time on this. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: And `console.log width` right after that gives you `undefined`? Hmm. Then it seems it isn't an async issue after all. Is it possible (and I'm getting into improbable territory here) that one of the `'width'` strings you're using might involve unicode characters? Try copy+pasting the one from the console into your code. I guess another possibility is that you've set `Number::toString()` to return `undefined`... heh. Try `console.log typeof object.width`.

Comment: @Trevor console.log width gives an error. no unicode characters in there just numbers. and console.log typeof object.width is undefined as well. I thought it could be a scope issue but the first console.log object gives all attributes. So weird.

Comment: @Aldo Ah, I misread your post about what `JSON.stringify` shows—it *is* an async problem! My answer, as posted above, is correct. Everything but `console.log object` is showing the true state of the object at the time of the `console.log`; `console.log object` is storing a reference to the object, then displaying it later, after the object's fields have been populated. **Use `JSON.stringify` when you want to avoid confusion!** Make sense?

Comment: @Travor Yes! you are right. it is an async problem. I passed async: false to ajaxOptions for AJAX call and it finally worked. Again thanks for your time.