# Variable value shown in console is inconsistent with equality test

Tags: comparison, coffeescript, equality

given the following:
where `data` is a string received as an AJAX value and data has a value of 'good':

```
console.log data          # good
console.log typeof data   # string
console.log typeof 'data' # string

if data is 'good'
  console.log 'test' # NOTHING!!!
```

I don't understand...

makes me want the good ol' JavaScript back...

A more complete example after a suggestion:

The following does not work either...

```
  $('#profile_slug').keyup(()->
    if $(this).val() != original_slug
      value = encodeURIComponent $(this).val()
      console.log value
      $.get('/live_validate/slug?slug='+value, (data)->

        console.log data
        console.log typeof data
        console.log typeof 'data'

        `
        if (data == 'good') {
          console.log('test');
        }

       `
```

#### update 2

oddly enough:

```
console.dir data
console.dir 'good'

good
No Properties

good
No Properties
```

#### update 3

*controller*

```
  if @slug.nil?
    @message = "good"
  else
    @message = "bad"
  end
```

*view*

```
!= @message
```

*coffeescript*

```
new_data = data.replace /^\s+|\s+$/g, ""
```

*result*

same sh*t.

### update 4 + answer

This code ended up being what I needed, at first it didn't work quite well with everything else I had going on, but it is the final piece in the puzzle, allowing me to make sure there are no invisible spaces before or after the received string.

```
    $.get('/live_validate/slug?slug='+value, (data)->
        # console.log data

        stripped_data = data.replace /^\s+|\s+$/g, ""

        # console.log encodeURIComponent data
        # console.log (data.charCodeAt(i) for i in [0...data.length])       


        if stripped_data is 'good'
          $('#profile_slug').addClass('valid-field')
          $('#profile_slug').removeClass('invalid-field')
        else if stripped_data is 'bad'
          $('#profile_slug').addClass('invalid-field')
          $('#profile_slug').removeClass('valid-field')
```

Comment: before the `if` stick a `console.dir data` and see what it really is.  It should pop into the console in a form you can drill into.

Comment: "good No Properties"

see updated question please.

Comment: what browsers have you tried this in?

Comment: you should look at the javascript it compiles to. does it look like what you expect it to? when you step through it, what happens?

Comment: I agree with Isaac.  The `is` operator is an alias for the `==` operator which both translate to the Javascript `===` operator.  There shouldn't be any other magic there.  If you don't see `if data is "good" console.log 'test'` translate into `if (data === "good") console.log('test')` then it might give you a clue to what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an invisible character at the end of the ajax response string... thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

This is weird, but my guess is that one of the two `'good'` strings in the comparison is using Unicode characters that resemble, but are not equal to, the ASCII characters you're expecting.

Try this:

```
console.log (data.charCodeAt(i) for i in [0...data.length])
```

When `data = 'good'`, I get

```
[ 103, 111, 111, 100 ]
```

Comment: It ended up being some weird space or something appended at the end of the string... "good%0A - [103, 111, 111, 100, 10]"

Comment: @Victor Glad I pointed you in the right direction. Care to upvote my answer?